# Cookie does not set

Tags: php, cookies

I have a cookie that will not set on the remote server, works find locally.  No error messages, var_dump gets me Null, echo is blank.

```
<php
 setcookie('ymp','14', time()+3600);
 session_start();
?>
```

I can set a javascript cookie fine. The opening tag is line 1 of the page.

Any ideas

Thanks 
Gary

On Edit

I have some comments I posted below, it is a 3 file process.

Page one is to set the cookie, as above.

Page two I have for debugging

```
<php var_dump($_COOKIE['ymp']); echo'<br />'.$_COOKIE['ymp'];?>
```

Page 3, and again this all worked locally I have

```
 <?php
 if($_COOKIE['ymp']!=='14')
 {die('Sorry, you have not had your delightful little pastry yet.... try again.');}
```

?>

I set a js cookie, and changed the code to reflect the different cookie name and it worked fine.

I also reset the time to +86400, because of the two hour time difference to the server, though I don't think that is really required.

Thanks for all the help

Gary

Comment: Are you aware that you are setting a cookie that will expire 3.6seconds after you set it?

Comment: @BrunoVieira that's not true.

Comment: @BrunoVieira `time()+3600` is 1 hour! its not milli seconds.

Comment: yes, I made a mistake, too much java recently

Comment: @Gary, what code are you using to read the cookie?

Comment: use firebug/httpfox type tools in your browser to see if the cookie header even comes through in the response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the value of a cookie until a new page request is made. This is because the value of cookie data is sent with the page request. So it isn't available for to access its value until *after* it is set and a new page request is made.

Also, `session_start()` has no effect on cookies. They are two different things. (Sessions do typically use cookies to store the session ID but that is irrelevant).

Comment: It apparently works on a local server, so I don't think the problem is not refreshing the page.

Comment: It is a 3 file process, first is the page that is supposed to set the cookie.  On page two, just for debugging purposes if have:   <?php var_dump($_COOKIE['ymp']); echo'<br />'.$_COOKIE['ymp'];?> On page 3, and again this all worked on local machine,      <?php if($_COOKIE['ymp']!=='14'){die('Sorry, you have not had your delightful little pastry yet.... try again.');}

Answer (score 0):

This is rather peculiar - I assume this could have something to do with PHP configuration.

See what the return value of `setcookie` function is - it [may be `FALSE`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#refsect1-function.setcookie-returnvalues) if output has been already sent before the function call. You did mention it is right at the start of your script, however there could be other entities outputting data (pre-executed scripts on the server perhaps?)

It's also possible that your browser is set to not accept cookies from certain domain - check your configuration.

Please provide any other relevant code and indicate how you check if cookies are set.

Comment: I check the cookies in both Chrome and Firefox developer tools as well as phpinfo() file I created to check php.ini.  I set the js cookie and it shows up on all 3, the php setcookie() does not. I have added a path, domain, reconfigured expiration to 36000...nuthin

Comment: Did you try to output result from `setcookie` to see if it at least reports to be successful?

Answer (score 0):

This problem never did solve, I ended up writing a new file to a different domain on the same host, gave the cookie a different name and value (is it possible that a 3 character name cookie with a 2 digit value too small??) and it worked as supposed expected.

Thank you all for your help... too busy to do a CSI investigation as to the how's and whys.

Gary

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you don't specify a path and/or a domain for the cookie. Try this instead:

```
<?php
    setcookie('ymp','14', time()+3600, '/', 'yourdomain.com')
?>
```